# How to calculate total price & grand total using keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

hy all ..
I have quetion about jquery keyup
1. how I can calculate total from quantity[] * price[]
2 how I can callculate grantotal from price[]

I have try like this but not working

Thanks

```js
   $('input[name="qty[]"').each(function(index, value){

    $('input[name="qty[]"').on('keyup',function(){

       
            var tot = $('input[name="price[]"').val() * this.value;
            $('input[name="subT[]"').val(tot);
           // console.log($('input[name="qty[]"'));

        })
            
  
    }); 
//});


$('input[name="qty[]').keyup(function () { 
    var sum = 0;
    $('.subT').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#grandtotal').val(sum);
     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$('input[name="price[]"]')
```

to

```
$('input[name="price[]"]').val()
```

So, it should look like this:

```
$('input[name="qty[]"]').keyup(function() {
    $('input[name="prodid[]"]').each(function() {
         var subT = parseFloat($(this).val()) * parseFloat($('input[name="price[]"]').val());
         $('input[name="total[]"]').val($(this).val() * $('input[name="price[]"]').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$('input[name="qty[]"]').keyup(function() {
  var total = (this.value * $(this).next('[name="price[]"]').val()) || 0;
  $(this).next().next('[name="total[]"]').val(total)


  var grand = 0;
  $('[name="total[]"]').each(function() {
    grand += +this.value || 0;
  });

  $('[name="grand_total"]').val(grand)
}).keyup();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="prodid[]" type="hidden" value="116">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" value="1" maxlength="2" class="detailinformation--input qty">
<input name="price[]" type="hidden" value="5">
<input name="total[]" type="hidden" value="">



<input name="prodid[]" type="hidden" value="117">
<input name="qty[]" type="text" value="1" maxlength="2" class="detailinformation--input qty">
<input name="price[]" type="hidden" value="4">
<input name="total[]" type="hidden" value="">



<input name="grand_total" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: hy Arun thanks for your answer but not working to me
i want just 
1. how I can calculate price from quantity[] * price[]
2 how I can callculate grantotal from price[]

Comment: @b4dQuetions there is no price value in the hidden input... so I just added some values.... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sy7zfy0y/2/